# OnActionExecuting(FilterExecutingContext) doesn't exist in System.Web.Mvc anymore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In preview 5 I was overriding the OnActionExecuting in my custom controller class, but now for some reason in beta it is giving me an error saying the parameter FilterExecutingContext doesn't exist?

```
     protected override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.FilterExecutingContext filterContext)
```

What is the parameter now?

Answer (score 19):

The parameter is now a System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext object.